# bash - command not found within bash script function

Tags: bash

Within a bash script, `script.sh`, I can call commands at the top level, but not within a function. How can I give access to the global context to the function?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# the following two commands work:
bash -c "echo hello"
docker

function fn() {
  # the following two commands fail:
  bash -c "echo hello"
  docker
}

fn
```

How do I give access to the global context to the function?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the comments - you made me realize that this minimal example wasn't reproducing my actual script.
By looking more in details, I realized that the problem is that in the function I overrode the `PATH` variable, thus breaking the global scope access.

Actual reproduction would be:

```
function fn() {
  PATH="somevalue"
  # the following two commands fail:
  bash -c "echo hello"
  docker
}
```

Solved it! Cheers!

Comment: is there an error message? fn should have global visibility. Also, the commands are based on the path and in your example have nothing to do with scoping I think - can you show us the problem better?

Comment: Why are you using `bash -c "echo hello"` and not just `echo hello`?

Comment: You changed `PATH` and thus the commands are no longer found in the PATH. What's surprising?

Comment: @usr: Nothing surprising, I just didn't realize I did that. I'm not from the bash world you see